# prevent div from overlapping for stacked div format

Tags: html, css

I am creating a vertical layout of stacked divs. Everything was going well until the `#resume` div, which keeps on hiding beneath the div containing a table above it. I tried changing float and position, but can't quite get the div underneath the `.samples` div. I tried to copy the code onto JS Fiddle, but the same problem does not appear. I would really appreciate any help.

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
    <head>
<title>Charles's Bio</title>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<html>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bio.css">

<nav>
<br>
<h1>Learn More About Charles</h1>
<p></p>



<div class="navrow">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#bout"><button>About Me</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="#work"><button>Work Samples</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="#resume1"><button>Resume</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="#blog1"><button>Blog</button></a></td>
        <td><a href="#contact1"><button>Contact</button></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
</nav>

<a NAME = "bout"></a>
<div class = "space"></div>
<div id="AboutPictures">
<img src="">
<h3>Charles is a Northwestern University senior majoring in Journalism. He is addicted to sports, YouTube, and quality journalism. Edward's favorite publications include the Wall Street Journal, Daily Northwestern and New York Times. You can often find him in the gym, coding, or watching NFL or NBA games. <h3>

</div>

<div class="samples">
<a NAME = "work"></a>
<div class = "space"></div>
<table>
    <th>Pokemon</th>
    <tr>
        <td>
                    <p>Squirtle is an amphibion Pokemon. He can shoot water and hide in his shell</p>
                    <img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//007.png">
        </td>
        <td>
                    <p>Hello Charzard</p>
                <img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//006.png">
        </td>

        <td>
                    <p>Hello Charzard</p>
            <img src = "http://assets.pokemon.com/assets/cms2/img/pokedex/full//001.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
                    <p>Hello Charzard</p>
            <img src = "http://vignette3.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/a/a5/Pikachu_digital_art_pokemon_by_dark_omni-d5wotdb.png/revision/latest?cb=20141113035440">
        </td>
        <td>
                    <p>Hello Charzard</p>
                <img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5f/Pok%C3%A9mon_Lugia_art.png">
            </td>
        <td>
                    <p>Hello Charzard</p>
                <img src = "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/pokemon/images/f/ff/Togepi.png/revision/latest?cb=20100731212849">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

<div id="resume"> <a NAME ="resume1"></a><div class = "space">Resume Page </div></div>

<div id="blog"><a NAME = "blog1"></a><div class = "space"><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>Blog Page</div></div>

<div id="contacts"><a NAME="contact1"></a><div class = "space">contact Page</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin: 0;
}
p{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}
h1{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}
nav{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: black;
    text-align: center;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:9999;
}
.navrow{
    background-color: white;
    width: 100%;
}
.navrow table td{
    padding-left: 150px;
}
button{
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;  
}

.aboutpage h1{
    color:red;
}

.samples {
    float: left;
    height: 70%;
    width: 100%;
}
#resume {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,200);
}
#blog {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,150);
    position: relative;
}
#contacts {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
#AboutPictures {
    float: right;
    background-color: rgb(0,200,255);
}

#AboutPictures h3{
    margin-left: 20px;
}
img[src*="tumblr"]{
    height:360px;
    width:40%;
    float: right;
    top: 10px;
    padding:0 0 0 0;

}

.biopage {
    position:relative;
}
.samples table{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
.samples td{
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    height:300px;
    position:relative;
    table-layout: fixed;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
}
.samples td img{
    width: 290px;
    height:290px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.samples td:hover img{
    opacity: .5;

}
.samples p{
    margin: 0;
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    right:0;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index:10;

}
.samples td:hover p{
    visibility: visible;
}
.samples td p{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.container{
    background color: white;
    width: 25%;
    float: right;
}
.container img{
    width: 100%;
}

.space {
    height:125px;
    background-color: rgb(0,300,300);
}
```

and a snapshot of the problem div:

[image: DIV]

```
`
```

Comment: JSFiddle is quite awesome at sharing issues and allowing people to help you quicker. https://jsfiddle.net/u4au3wc8/

Comment: yes, I should have added it, but what appears on jsfiddle is different from what appears on my browser

Comment: I found that adding changing `<div class="samples">
<a NAME = "work"></a>
<div class = "space"></div>` to `<a NAME = "work"></a>
<div class = "space"></div>
<div class="samples">` fixed the problem. Not sure why this is the case though.

Answer (score 0):

Use Z-Index to place higher priority on .samples. The higher the Z-Index given, will put it above other layers. Your current CSS for .samples is at 0.